# Show native system messages C#

Tags: c#, windows, system, message

Is there a way to show the native Windows messages, like "your pc needs to be restarted" or "Windows has recovered from an error", using C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MessageBox` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx